# Multiple scheduling and mailing of reports in SpringBoot using multiple CRON strings

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

There are multiple reports and the execution of reports need to be scheduled at some time using cron strings. So different reports will have different cron strings configured to them. Then after execution, reports need to be mailed to certain email addresses at the same time. I need to write the code for this in JAVA/SpringBoot framework. I know that there is a Scheduled annotation provided in SpringBoot for scheduling a task, which takes cron string as a parameter. But here there are multiple cron strings, so Scheduled annotation will not work ig. It is more of a design problem. I am providing a pseudocode to explain what I want.

```
//map to store which report needs to get executed at which cron
Map<cronString, reportName> reportMap;
void schedulingAndMailing(){
   //some time for which we have a cron string
   String reportNames = reportMap.get(cron which gets triggered);
   FileTransfer reportFile = executeReport(reportName);
   //need to send this report file to mail
   sendMail(reportFile);
}
```

Comment: So depending on ReportName you need to schedule? Suppose for report A you need to send everyday ,but for report B you need to send everyhour ? Is my assumption correct?!

Comment: Yes correct. Different reports will have different cron strings. According to those cron strings, it needs to be first get executed and then sent.